Chinese remainder theorem for finite rings.
Let R be a finite commutative ring with its only maximal ideals I and J. Let n and m be their index of stability ,i.e., $I^n=I^{n+1}=\cdots$ and $J^m=J^{m+1}=\cdots.$ How to prove that the ideals $I^n$ and $J^m$ are coprime and $I^nJ^m=0$?
I could prove that $I^n+J^m=R,$ hence proving coprime. However, I cannot prove the fact that $I^nJ^m=I^n \cap J^m=0.$ Please give me some idea how to proceed.

Observe that $I^nJ^m \supseteq (I \cap J)(I^n J^m) \supseteq (IJ)I^nJ^m = I^nJ^m$. Do you see why $I^nJ^m$ is finitely generated? Can you conclude the proof using Nakayama's lemma?

yes! Thank you.
